# Continuous function which is always rational

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be a continuous function such that $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q} $, $\forall x\in \mathbb{R} $. Is it true that the only functions with this property are the constant functions? Intuitively, I believe it is, but I am not sure.
EDIT: I had a typo, the relation holds $\forall x\in \mathbb{R} $. I am sorry for my mistake.

Comment: What about $f(x)=x$?

Comment: In fact, any polynomial with rational coefficients works as well.

Comment: OP, do you mean $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo, sorry folks!

Comment: After your edit, constant functions of the type $f(x) = c$, for $c \in \mathbb{Q}$ are the only "allowed" ones. This follows from the intermediate value theorem and the fact that there always is a irrational number between two arbitrary distinct rationals.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if a continuous function $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ takes only rational values, then it must be a constant function.

Assume not, then there exist distinct real numbers $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that 
$$
f(x_1) = q_1, f(x_2) = q_2
$$
where $q_1,q_2 \in \Bbb Q$ are distinct rationals. Since $f$ is continuous, the [Intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem)
 says that $f$ must takes all real value between $q_1$ and $q_2$. There are infinitely many irrational numbers between $q_1$ and $q_2$, which contradicts the fact that the range of $f$ is in $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 1):

No, $f(x)$ could be any polynomial function with rational coefficients.  Polynomial functions are continuous, and a polynomial with rational coefficients evaluated at a rational number is rational.

Comment: Ditto for rational functions without poles.

Comment: This is no longer correct after OP's edit. (The question originally asked for continuous $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}\ \  \forall x \in \color{red}{\mathbb{Q}}$.)

Comment: Yes, but it is not his fault, it is my bad